# Java ZipInputStream Exception throws before code is even executed

Tags: java, exception

I have Java code which passes in a list of Zip Files, one of which is purposely badly formatted.  This Zip file is placed at the end of the list.

My code looks somewhat like:

```
System.out.println("Hi Stinky Pete ");
try
{
    for (File files : file)
    {
       zip_str = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
       yada;
    }
}
catch(Exception)
{
}
```

It never prints "Hi Stinky Pete" or processes any File before it gets to the bad zip file, which is the 4th or 20th file in the list, it just throws the ZipException.  ALSO, I cannot catch the ZipException!  It always bubbles up and terminates my program.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you post the output?

Comment: 1. Which line is the exception thrown from? 2.You may see a difference between the sysout and exception log (syserr) because they are processed by separate threads. Can you try debugging the program to confirm the actual flow?

Answer (score 0):

Is this malformed ZIPfile on your classpath by any chance? Or do you have a static initializer in your class that tries to open it?

Take a close look at the exception *stack trace* to see where it's being thrown. If you can't interpret it, then *post the stack trace in your question*.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize but I had inherited code.  The code I inherited performed a loop through file list, casting them to `ZipFile` in a separate running thread.  This was why I could not catch it or get the StackTrace. Basically it was,

```
for( File files : file)
{
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);
}
```

They were doing this to check they Zip file but weren't catching.  Sorry for the post!